# How to retrieve a particular value from a single row table in html by using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I was wondering how to retrieve a particular value, in this case "2" (from below html code) by using JQuery. Notice the code represents just a single table row (since data-rowindex="0",it represents the first table row).

```
  <tr role="row" class="abc" data-rowindex="0">
    <td data-title="Car">
      <span name="id-car">Audi</span>
    </td>
    <td class="Carnumber" data-title="Number">
       <span name="id-carnum">2</span>
    </td>
     <td class="Carcolor" data-title="Color">0</td>
     <td class="CarYear" data-title="CarYear">0</td>
  </tr>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following makes use of the row index:

```
$("tr[data-rowindex=0]>.Carnumber>span").text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign an Id to your table, in my case I used id="mytable", then use following function

```
$(function () { 
 $('#mytable tr').each(function() {
    var customerId = $(this).find("span[name='id-carnum']").html(); 
    alert(customerId);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fyi using $('<example-element>').val(); only works on input elements.

$(function() {
    $('td.Carnumber').each(function(index, element) {

        $(this).find("span[name='id-carnum']").text();

    });
})();
```